# TBATS requires positive data after differencing - forecast package R

Tags: r, tbats

I need to difference the series once to get a stationary series but then cannot run the tbats function because my differenced series has negative values. Does anyone know of any way of handling with this? I'm thinking of adding a constant but don't know whether I'm cheating or not.

Comment: It looks like earlier versions of the `forecast` package required nonnegative values for `tbats()`. [Version 7.1 seems to check for this and can fit a TBATS model even on negative values](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224053/1352), presumably just skipping the Box-Cox transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tbats()` does not require a stationary series. So don't difference.