# forecast::tbats() gives missing value error for zeros

Tags: r, forecasting, multiple-seasonalities, tbats

I used tbats to find the best fit model to a 3 years of daily data.

It could not find a model and showed the following error: `Missing values encountered. Using longest contiguous portion of time series`.

I checked my data and there is no missing data. I only have a lot of "0" in my data. Is this error related to too many "0"s that the data has?

Comment: We can't judge between you and the software on this evidence. But be clear: gaps in data (e.g. days omitted) and missing values (e.g. values of whatever code is used for "missing", such as NA) are different things, but the former can count as missing for some programs. Additionally, 0s may be a problem for some time series models. As you don't say what kind of a model you are fitting, it is, again, hard to judge.

Comment: I saw double seasonality in my data so I used tbats to see what model it fits to my data. "0" in my data are not missing values. there were no orders in some days so the amount of the order was 0. How can I check to see if too many 0 are making a problem for my data? About 10% of my data is "0".

Comment: Cloning the data and changing the zeros to something else would be a check on whether the software is choking on zeros.

Comment: I did and yes "0"s were the source of error. I changed all "0"s to 0.1 and now it can find a fitted model. I wonder if this model is reliable. I mean is it reasonable to change "0"s to a small number and then find a fitted model?Thanks

Comment: I think that is a whole new question in itself, which you might post as a new thread. Some time series models don't make sense unless values remain positive. Again, what model you are using is crucial detail. Just saying you used particular software is not informative: for a start, people in this field use a variety of different programs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will search in this forum to see if I can find useful information about my question.

Answer (score 1):

The "B" in the TBATS model stands for "Box-Cox transformation", which does not make sense for nonpositive data. Of course, the software should be checking whether all data are strictly positive before attempting such a transformation.

Unfortunately, you do not say what version of the `forecast` package you are using. With my version 7.1, `forecast::tbats()` does not have problems with zero values:

```
library(forecast)
series <- msts(rep(1:10,10),seasonal.periods=c(10,20))
tbats(series)
tbats(series-1)
```

I suspect that you have run into a bug that has since been fixed.

In addition, I am slightly wary of you having detected [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities) in data with zeros. In my experience, detecting even single [seasonality](/questions/tagged/seasonality) in intermittent data is hard.